# Eclipse remove arrow icons

Tags: java, eclipse

When I click on some word inside the java editor, it marks it together with all occurrences, which is wonderful. As you can see in my screenshot, I've customized it to be green, this green will also show near the slide bar on the right.

[image]

What I don't like: the red marked arrows on the left, next to the line numbers. They "show" me the occurrences as well as it seems, but honestly they don't give me any profit as my bright green marking is way faster recognized by me than those arrows.
Plus, and this is the annoying part, these arrows block visibility of my debug points, which will be placed underneath such an arrow. Did you see that the second arrow is actually hiding a debug point? Me neither...

So: is there a way to disable these arrows by eclipse preferences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Vertical Ruler** should be switched off.

Please search for 'Mark Occurrences' in Window -> Preferences. 
Then click on the link 'Annotations' and then uncheck 'Vertical ruler'.

Comment: Bingo - awesome! While I'm at it I also removed the "search results" vertial ruler, works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: In my Eclipse Juno, its in Window => Preference, General => Editors => Text Editors => Annotations. In Annotation Types box, look for "Search Results" and uncheck 'Vertical ruler'.